# foreach in Makefile not finding all files

Tags: c++, foreach, makefile

I am trying to write a generic Makefile and trying to use "foreach" to search all files in my project. There are about 250 files in multiple directors but I can't seem to be able to get this right. Any ideas why it is not working?

```
SRCDIRS = ./Src
SRCEXTS = .c .cpp
HDREXTS = .h

SOURCES = $(foreach $(SRCDIRS),$(SRCDIRS),$(wildcard $(addprefix $(d)/*,$(SRCEXTS))))
HEADERS = $(foreach $(SRCDIRS),$(SRCDIRS),$(wildcard $(addprefix $(d)/*,$(HDREXTS))))
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$(foreach $(SRCDIRS),$(SRCDIRS)` does that look right to you? What about in relation to `$(addprefix $(d)/*,$(SRCEXTS))`? Where is `$(d)` coming from? That being said you only have one `$(SRCDIRS)` in that snippet but I assume you have more in the real makefile? [This post](http://blog.jgc.org/2011/07/gnu-make-recursive-wildcard-function.html) might be of some use here also.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this:

```
SOURCES = $(foreach d,$(SRCDIRS),$(wildcard $(addprefix $(d)/*, $(SRCEXTS))))
HEADERS = $(foreach d,$(SRCDIRS),$(wildcard $(addprefix $(d)/*, $(HDREXTS))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`wildcard` can't search file recursively. So the files in sub-directory can't be found.

```
CPP_SRCS = $(shell find . -iname "*.cpp")
```

works.